# How to enable open source radeon driver for a Radeon HD 5570?

Tags: upgrade, ati, radeon, fglrx

I upgraded from Ubuntu 11.04 (using fglrx driver from AMD site) to 11.10. After upgrade 3D acceleration is not working with my Radeon HD 5570 fails to run any program with 3D acceleration. I tried to remove ATI driver and reinstall it but to no avail. I also tried Live CD and there open source driver works great, but I don't know how to enable it on my computer.

[Uninstalling fglrx](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver) didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: try this.  http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx

Comment: Just tried it, didn't help. I am starting to believe reinstalling of OS is the option.

Comment: just looked at dmesg; it seems there are parts of fglrx remaining. I'll see what I can do

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Do this to remove all the fglrx traces from your system:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
```

Remove your xorg.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Reinstall xorg

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
```

Configure Xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

After the reboot all the fglrx drivers will be gone, you will be using default ones.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  Thanks.  It's one of those things you can usually work your way out of when there's a problem, but your instructions worked first shot.  My only difference was I didn't have the i386 packages installed in the first place so I omitted them.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem indeed was previous ATI driver. It was removed, using command:

```
sudo ./ati-driver-installer-11-9-x86.x86_64.run --uninstall=force
```

the executable was downloaded from AMD ATI homepage.