# Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?

Tags: ati

I have an ATI graphics card and I want to know if it is supported and what kind of drivers should I be running to get the best features out of it.

Is my card supported in Ubuntu and what drivers will work with my card?

Comment: Duplicate and merge this? http://askubuntu.com/q/124292/169736

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### Officially Supported Hardware

To check if your card is supported visit [this site](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware).

If you card is not listed there then probably it is too new and simply is not supported by any ATI driver.

### Installation of the drivers

Before installing any drivers you need to install some dependencies to your system, do this by running this command

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
```

**Official binary packages from Ubuntu**

To install the `fglrx` packages supplied by Ubuntu open a terminal and install using

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

or search for the `Additional Drivers` utility in your dash and install one of the detected drivers from the list.

Latest version provided by Ubuntu's `Additional Drivers` tool (up to this edit's date) is 11.10.

---

**Official ATI binaries from the ATI site**

To install the latest ATI 15.9 drivers follow this, people are reporting that updating their driver solves some problems with Unity and Gnome-Shell

You will need to remove all the current `fglrx` packages from your system and download the driver from the ATI site.

Remove the fglrx drivers if previously installed them (if any of these returns errors ie: *file not found*, *package not found* ignore it)

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

Download the newest ATI driver (current version is 15.9)

```
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-15-9-x86.x86_64.run
```

**If you have a 64 bit system, then install this before anything**

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Once downloaded go to the file location and set it to run as executable

```
cd /path_of_the_file
chmod 755 amd-driver-installer-15-9-x86.x86_64.run
```

*For 32/64 bit Ubuntu use these steps to install*

```
sh ./amd-driver-installer-15-9-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/oneiric
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```

Once the driver is installed you need to start up a new xorg.conf file with this command

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

### Revert back to the open source drivers

**After installing drivers from deb packages**

Remove all the fglrx traces from your system:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

Remove your xorg.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Reinstall xorg

*For 32bits systems*

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
```

*For 64bits systems*

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 xserver-xorg-core
```

Configure Xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

After the reboot all the fglrx packages will be gone, you will be using default ones.

---

**After installing drivers from ATI binary**

Remove all the ATI driver files:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
```

Remove your xorg.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Reinstall xorg

*For 32bits systems*

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
```

*For 64bits systems*

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 xserver-xorg-core
```

Configure Xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

After the reboot all the fglrx drivers will be gone, you will be using default ones.

Comment: “If you have a 64 bit system, then install this before anything: sudo apt-get install ia32-libs”... Is this remark still valid for Ubuntu 12.04? Given that -as I understand it- packages are now multiarch and ia32-libs should no longer be needed?

Comment: To answer my own question, see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-in-12-04-lts

Comment: Just a note, the current ATI driver url is http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run

Comment: @kiswa I will fix that soon. On a side note, if you see something wrong on the site you can always fix it yourself if its useful ;)

Comment: Thanks, I knew that. ;)  I somehow didn't notice it was community wiki! EDIT: Also, I went ahead and edited the 12.3 to 12.4

Comment: I had a very recent problem with Unity, I followed the steps of "Installation of the Drivers" rebooted and it all worked. One this to note is that I am using ati-13.1 driver

Comment: FYI the ati.com links do not work anymore

Comment: The link wget http://www2.ati.com/... is broken.

Comment: ATI doesn't care for redirects from other sites. Download the latest drivers as needed at http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux

Answer (score 5):

I have found that the default, open driver works best with my ATI card (5450).  I had installed a proprietary driver that Ubuntu recommends, but had issues with shutdown crashing.  I uninstalled the proprietary driver, and I don't notice any difference in performance at all, but all I use it for is the Compiz effects, no games.

Answer (score 2):

There's atleast three drivers available with newer ATI cards. THere's the open source driver. It's reliable but not always the fastest. THen there's the fglrx driver shipped with the operating system or from jockey. It's faster and propably working. And then there's the fglrx driver downloadable from ATI.

The open source drivers is actually quite good. Try that one first.

Answer (score 2):

Many ATI video cards work well with Ubuntu automatically. To check that 3d acceleration works with your card, see the section called "Introduction to 3D Video Acceleration". If it does not work, this procedure should activate it.

Install the xorg-driver-fglrx package from the Restricted repository (see Chapter 2, Adding, Removing and Updating Applications).

You now need to configure the computer to use the new driver so run this command in a terminal:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
When the dialogue appears and asks whether to do automatic detection of your video, pick Yes.

When asked to select a driver, pick fglrx.

Follow the remaining instructions as appropriate.

Restart your machine for changes to take effect.