# getting compiz to work with Ubuntu 11.10 and fglrx

Tags: compiz, ati

I am trying to get Compiz to work in Ubuntu 11.10. I have FGLRX installed and the "Additional Drivers" screen seems to report that FGLRX is active and currently in use. I have tried using CCSM to enable the desktop cube. It seems to be enabled, yet I cannot get the affect, or any of the other compiz affects (e.g. wobbly windows) to actually happen. I would also like to get the scale plugin work.

My questions are:

- what do I need to do to make sure that FGLRX is running (I have an HP dv7 laptop with both Intel and ATi graphics)?
- once the graphics are setup correctly, what do I do to get the desktop cube and the scale addon to actually work?

Thank you for the help.

---

Update

```
stevejb@telegraph:~$ glxinfo | grep direct
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  12
  Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

---

Update

Reinstalling the open source ati drivers seemed to fix the problem. All is working now.

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu

Comment: can you split this off into 2 questions? This works best when there is one post per question.

Answer (score 1):

ccsm doesn't enables compiz, it just configures it. So you have the cube set in compiz but your desktop is running metacity.

Try to run in a terminal (maybe you'll need to unstall mesa-utils to run this):

```
glxinfo | grep direct
```

The output should tell you "direct rendering: Yes (if the drivers are properly installed) Then try:

```
compiz --replace
```

That should activate compiz. If not, it's a drivers problem.

If it works, maybe you have to do it every time you log in. To make it easier you can install fusion-icon:

```
sudo apt-get install fusion-icon
```

It allows you to switch between compiz and metacity with a click. Later if you want to run compiz automatically on login (if you don't find any problem) you can add the compiz --replace command to the startup applications.

Whish it helps.

Comment: stevejb@telegraph:~$ glxinfo | grep direct
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  12
  Current serial number in output stream:  12
stevejb@telegraph:~$ 

YIKES! It seems that something isn't working right.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by reinstalling the open source ati driver and completely purging fglrx.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [Ubuntu Oneiric Installation Guide ATI drivers](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide) work for me, unfortunately the official ATI drivers not work with the gnome-shell :( but work fine in Unity and classic

Answer (score 0):

This has solution:

Press CTRL+ALT+F1 and enter in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove - purge fglrx*
sudo amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64.run
```

This last line in my case, generates the package and then install the driver.