# ATI proprietary driver (post release) install fails. How can I fix it?

Tags: drivers, ati, gnome, jockey

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics install fails, how can I resolve the problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78906/ati-amd-proprietary-fglrx-graphics-install-fails-how-can-i-resolve-the-problem)

If ATI post release driver is selected, install fails.

How can I fix it? And I don't mean compiling and installing myself the ATI driver from command line, but to make the "Additional drivers" application work correctly.

Is there a bug for this in launchpad?

Comment: install the other ati driver shown in "additional drivers",it worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

Package with driver version of 11.9 **fglrx** [has been merged](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fglrx&searchon=names&suite=oneiric&section=all) or dropped I believe, there is no more the post release package [listed for 11.10](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer). To install the current driver select package marked as **current**. Note that current installs package with 8.881, that is the 11.8 catalyst driver.

If you need the latest ATI 11.10 drivers have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu) for instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's bad then :(. gnome-shell doesn't work with the 11.8, it has to be 11.9

Comment: That is incorrect, 11.9 breaks gnome-shell and unity, the version you need is 11.10 not 11.09.

Comment: Here is a nice simple how to, to install the latest amd/ati driver.  http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29