# ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics install fails, how can I resolve the problem?

Tags: software-installation, jockey

I want to activate ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (post-release update), but there is a problem during installation. It says:

> Sorry, installation of this driver failed.
>
> Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log

How can I install this driver?

Answer (score 16):

Remove and [purge](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/apt-get.8.html) the current version, then install the updates:

1. `sudo apt-get --purge remove fglrx*`
2. `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates`
3. Reboot

**Making sure fglrx is fully removed is an important step.** It didn't work for me the first time I tried to install the updates and in the end I removed each fglrx package individually, purged each one individually, removed no longer dependencies `sudo apt-get autoremove`, rebooted, then installed the updates `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates`, rebooted, and (as of writing) I got catalyst version 11.11 *(which still doesn't work with gnome3)*.

### 12.10

- 21 Oct 2012 - `fglrx` is not working in 12.10, see [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/fglrx/+bug/1068661).
- 4 Jan 2013 - no fix yet, [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer-updates/+bug/1068404) [reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer-updates/+bug/1069199) are on fire,
- 27 July 2013 - Still no fix *sigh*

#### 12.10 Troubleshooting

If you have problems with graphics after installing or updating to 12.10, you will need to remove `fglrx` and use open source drivers:

```
    $ sudo apt-get remove fglrx*
```

If you get stuck on a warning about "low graphics":

1. Open the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Remove fglrx: `sudo apt-get remove fglrx*`
3. Reboot: `sudo reboot`

For more see the SO question [Can't install ATI proprietary drivers in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10).

### 13.04

- 27 July 2013 - `fglrx` does not work. *sigh*

### Notes

- What packages are currently installed? `dpkg -l fglrx*`

  ```
  $ dpkg -l fglrx*
  un  fglrx          <none>         (no description available)
  un  fglrx-amdcccle <none>         (no description available)
  ii  fglrx-amdcccle 2:8.911-0ubunt Catalyst Control Center for the AMD graphics
  un  fglrx-control  <none>         (no description available)
  un  fglrx-control- <none>         (no description available)
  un  fglrx-driver   <none>         (no description available)
  un  fglrx-kernel-s <none>         (no description available)
  un  fglrx-modalias <none>         (no description available)
  ii  fglrx-updates  2:8.911-0ubunt Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerato
  ```

  - [What do the various dpkg flags like 'ii' 'rc' mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18804/what-do-the-various-dpkg-flags-like-ii-rc-mean)
- [Confirm the drivers are working](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI) `fglrxinfo`

  ```
  $ fglrxinfo 
  display: :0  screen: 0
  OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6300M Series
  OpenGL version string: 4.2.11733 Compatibility Profile Context
  ```
- For Catalyst <=11.11 with gnome <=3.2 *Expect screen flickering and system hangs.*
- [AMD Catalyst Proprietary Display Driver - Linux x86 & Linux x86_64](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx)
- Get device information: `lspci` or verbose `lspci -vv`

Answer (score 7):

All Jockey does is install *fglrx* and *fglrx-amdcccle* in the case of normal drivers, and *fglrx-updates* and *fglrx-amdcccle-updates* when you select the post-release updates option, though it fails somehow for I don't know what reason.

You can simply install/activate *ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (post-release update)* option by typing the following line into the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
```

or search for these packages within the Ubuntu Software Center and install them from there.

Answer (score 3):

An excellent resource for installing the latest driver from ATI and easy to follow.  [Installing Catalyst latest driver from ATI in Ubuntu 11.10](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29)

Bob Bowles (ed.): I found the ATI download site very user-friendly, with good self-documentation on the download/build/deploy process. [ATI Download site](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

On my T400 laptop, the ATI mobility radeon graphics card has become unsupported by the latest 13.10 fglrx driver.

```
(II) Module fglrx: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
   compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 13.10.10

$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV620/M82 [Mobility Radeon HD 3450/3470]
$ lspci -n | grep 01:00.0
01:00.0 0300: 1002:95c4
```

The /var/log/Xorg.0.log shows this line:

> (EE) No supported AMD display adapters were found

Fixed by downgrading and locking the fglrx package with synaptic manager:
http://www.howtogeek.com/117929/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu/

As text:

1. start synaptic
2. search for the fglrx package
3. choose menu Package -> force version
4. after selecting the earlier version, click apply
5. choose menu Package -> lock version

Now Steam on Linux works again too.