# Lenovo OneKey Recovery System on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, ati, lenovo

I am always confused whether to use Ubuntu/Win. This time as my HDD had some factory problems, Lenovo replace it for free. So, I have a fresh new HDD on which I would like to use Ubuntu (I did have some hands-on experience on Ubuntu for 1 yr).

But I am worried whether the special features of lenovo would work in it as I didn't get drivers for Linux when I brought my laptop. Neither they are present in the website.

I use Lenovo G570.

1. Does the one key recovery system work in Ubuntu and how do I install it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. And about your second question, try [this link](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29), it was suggested in an answer to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/a/93650/18887)

Comment: Okay, for now I would do that. I will be deleting the second question form this

Answer (score 2):

On a N586, I have just installed 12.10 alongside Windows 7 and kept the OKR working.  I did not find an exact **how-to** anywhere on line, so did it my way.  It worked (so far !). You need to be comfortable repartitioning.

Problem is that Lenonv uses 4 primary partitions for their Windows 7 install.  Solution is to turn the main Windows_OS partition `C:` into a logical one - this works because Windows actually boots from the 200MB SYSTEM partition which is still primary.  Then you can shrink the `C:` drive and run the Ubuntu install which will use the remaining space.  I contemplated making the `D:` drive logical as well, but was not sure if OKR would get upset.  Seems simple but it took ages to make it happen.

I have Windows 7, Ubuntu and OKR all working.

Some specifics:

1. Make rescue disk and full recovery disk set first!  Most folks recommend two copies, just in case.
2. I used a bootable partitioning tool (GParted) to re-characterize the Windows_OS space
3. Then back into Windows to use the Disk Management tool to shrink the windows partition (hint:  defragment it first to shift some files down)
4. Then run Ubuntu install.  You could manually partition, but I tried the "install alongside...." option and it worked a dream

As for hardware compatibility, the only thing I'm struggling with is the internal microphone. Everything else seems to work out of the box.

Good luck!