# Only HDMI Soundcard listed, not onboard (Ideacenter Q180)

Tags: sound, ati, pulseaudio, hdmi, soundcard

My Ubuntu 12.10 system on Lenovo Ideacenter Q180 sees only the HDMI soundcard, but not the onboard one. How can I fix this?

lshw output:

```
Audio device
/0/100/1c.3/0.1
product: Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6400 Series] [1002:AA98]
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI [1002]
bus info: pci@0000:04:00.1
version: 00
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities:
    Power Management,
    PCI Express,
    Message Signalled Interrupts,
    bus mastering,
    PCI capabilities listing
configuration:
    driver: snd_hda_intel
    latency: 0
resources:
    irq: 51
    memory: d0040000-d0043fff
```

aplay:

```
sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
    Subdevices: 0/1
```

lspci:

```
sudo lspci | grep Aud
04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6400 Series]
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the Audio is handled by the video driver. The fglrx video driver has to be installed. How this is done was answered in [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78906/ati-amd-proprietary-fglrx-graphics-install-fails-how-can-i-resolve-the-problem). In my case I actually installed "fglrx-experimental-9" package, because even now when sound was working youtube videos were not fluent.

Finally, to get everything working really smothly as a media center pc I recommend installing [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/).