# What is the difference between fglrx* and fglrx?

Tags: drivers, fglrx

Is there a difference between `fglrx*` and `fglrx`?

What is the meaning of `*` if added??

I did use the following steps because I was not sure whether I've had a graphic driver or not. So I wanted to activate a driver...

[ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics install fails, how can I resolve the problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78906/ati-amd-proprietary-fglrx-graphics-install-fails-how-can-i-resolve-the-problem)

Then many problems occured - like changes of the quality of the desktop environment - and I wanted to know if they happened because of the difference of `*`?

I am a new Ubuntu 12.04 user. Was it wrong to have purged `fglrx*`? I also get this error each time I boot Ubuntu since then:

> The disk drive for `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1` is not ready yet or not present

I would be really glad if someone could help me out!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `*` is a "wildcard" character, it basically means "any number of characters".

For example, let's say you have three packages/programs installed called `fglrx` and `fgrlx-updates`, and `fglrx-amdcccle`. If you only want to remove `fglrx`, you will use `apt-get remove fglrx`. If you want to remove all three of them, you'll have to do `apt-get remove fglrx fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle`. However, an easier way would be to do `apt-get remove fglrx*`, which means remove all packages that **start** with `fglrx`.

In the steps of the link you provided, the person mentioned `sudo apt-get --purge remove fglrx*`. This is to ensure that you remove **all** packages related to `fglrx`, so you can start all over and install only the needed packages. So to answer your question, yes, that command removed your ATI graphics drivers, and made Ubuntu use the open source drivers, that's why the quality of the desktop environment changed.

I suggest you now run the command `sudo apt-get --purge remove fglrx*`, then `sudo apt-get autoremove`, then restart, then use the Additional Drivers to install, then reboot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! :D I didnt think of such a good explained answer!

But unfortunately I don't have the application: "Software & Updates".

In the Sytsem Settings/ Additional Drivers ; I did try to activate an AMD/ATI driver but it failed with the same statement the whole thing began... : 


    Sorry, installation of this driver failed.

    Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log

Comment: Oh, okay. Well, try following the steps in that other question again. Read all the links the accepted answer provided, like the bug reports for it not working on 12.10. If you've tried everything, searched everywhere, and still failed, you can ask another question for the driver issues.

Comment: Alright, I'll go on reading. Thanks again!

Ive also had problems in my desktop enviroment (also like not being able to turn off bluetooth) before but they disappeared when I did update my kernel to 3.5
Do you think there is a connection between graphic driver issues and kernel?

Comment: Almost everything depends on the kernel =).

Comment: Yah, thats right!! After I messed up my Ubuntu 12.04 to a black screen at booting - probably cause I deleted things which I should not have; I just upgraded my kernel from an older version I picked up at booting and like magic; Ubuntu could start again..