# Black screen when booting Ubuntu after GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

So I installed Ubuntu 13.10 as the primary OS on my laptop. I installed Windows 8 in another partition and set up GRUB to be the boot loader. Eventually I updated Windows and it became a black screen so I reinstalled Windows in that partition. Somehow doing this removed Windows from GRUB's menu and so I tried to reinstall GRUB which I had a little trouble doing. I tried it a few different ways, one of them was booting from a LiveCD and involved mounting and unmounting things (did this pretty much blindly as I don't have a lot of the know how). That didn't work but I came across the standard boot-repair program and it worked fine.

The big problem I have no is that Ubuntu does not load after selecting it from GRUB. It just hangs at a black screen. When I select recovery mode, it goes to the menu. When I resume the normal boot, it reads out:

`Ubuntu 13.10 Denjay-Laptop tty1`

`Denjay-Laptop login:_`

With a flashing underscore. After a few seconds it then adds to that line `initct1: Event failed`

I also checked all the file systems with the recovery mode and with a LiveCD and nothing was anomalous on that end. I've also gone through updating GRUB so I think something wrong post-GRUB if that makes sense.

I heard that it might be a video card problem so I tried `nomodeset` which still resulted in a black screen. One user had too many drivers installed on their card and they input `dpkg --get-selections nvidia-*` to show their drivers. My laptop has "amd a8 3520m apu with radeon tm hd graphics" and I'm not sure what the driver package name for that is. So what should I replace `nvidia` with for to get the driver?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'` (http://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system)

Comment: That returned `Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci`

Comment: So try `dpkg --get-selections flgrx*`

Comment: And that returned `fglrx` `deinstall`; `fglrx-amdcccle-updates` `install`; `fglrx-updates` `install`

Comment: Try following the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/78906/ati-amd-proprietary-fglrx-graphics-install-fails-how-can-i-resolve-the-problem

Comment: Should I be able to do all that from the root shell in recovery mode? I tried `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdccle-updates` and that returned `W: Not using locking for read only file /var/lib/dpkg/lock` and `E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/` and `E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.`

Comment: What happens if you try to run those update packages you listed before?

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to run those.

Comment: Just type `fglrx-updates install`

Comment: `fglrx-updates: command not found` Just for clarification, when I entered `dpkg --get-selections flgrx*` it returned each of those `fglrx...` on the left side of the screen and then `install` on the right side. They were listed on the same line but opposite sides of the screen.

Comment: Hmm... okay, I'm not sure. Sorry