# I can not install drivers for ATI Radeon HD 6770

Tags: drivers, video, radeon, ati

I can not install drivers for ATI Radeon HD 6770. Here comes the message: **Sorry, this driver installation failed.
Please refer to the log file for more information: / var / log / jockey.log**

From **jockey.log**
ati2011-12-02 19:39:47,493 DEBUG: updating jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x1a088c0>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post-upgrade drivers are no more, you need to install the recommended ones (Catalyst 11.8) or download directly from the ATI site.

For more information check this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu).