# Graphics Driver for my new laptop asus x43ta(Radeon HD 6720G2 1gb is mentioned here

Tags: ati

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu)

I am new with Linux.
Pls specify the Graphics Driver for my new laptop asus x43ta(Radeon HD 6720G2 1gb is mentioned on the laptop. 
And also for my Desk top graphics card Asus EAH3450/HTP/512M Graphic Card works with m2n32sli deluxe asus board and athlon x2 6000+ prossessor. 3D games shows no smooth ness at presently
Greets and thanks

Comment: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx