# How can I enable hardware acceleration for an ATI Radeon HD?

Tags: 11.10, ati

When playing high definition video (720p and 1080p) the CPU reaches 100% and freezes the image at regular intervals.

According to the manufacturer this accelerator is capable of hardware acceleration for HD video.

Clearly something is not right.

This is the output of `vainfo`:

```
ivan@ivan-NT-A2400-NT-A3500:~$ vainfo
libva: libva version 0.32.0
Xlib:  extension "XFree86-DRI" missing on display ":0.0".
libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/fglrx_drv_video.so
libva: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

---

Thanks for the help.

Here you have the information of `vainfo`:

```
ivan@ivan-NT-A2400-NT-A3500:~$ vainfo
libva: libva version 0.32.0
Xlib:  extension "XFree86-DRI" missing on display ":0.0".
libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/fglrx_drv_video.so
libva: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

I have not yet installed / uninstalled anything in the system. This PC came with the system preinstalled. ATI drivers are installed.

Here I have picture with info on X:

[image]

---

Sorry:

This image shows `vainfo` information and drivers of my system.

[image]

Comment: I have changed the title of your post to support a more broad range of cards, the answers should apply to all ATI cards running the binary drivers.

Comment: sorry, but this is wrong. AFAIK, only ati cards supporting UVD2 and later support xvba, meaning cards radeon hd 4000 and later. see [wiki-entry xvba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Video_Bitstream_Acceleration)

Comment: @severin thx absolutly correct. answer changed.

Comment: As said on the post bellow, hardware video decoiding is only enable on the ATI binaries, you need to install them correctly before being able to use it. Follow [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu) to install the drivers for you card and dont forget to check is you card is supported first (link for that is also on the post).

Answer (score 13):

**Tested for Ubuntu 11.10 and any supported card ATI card using binary driver (only cards that support UDV2, radeon hd 4000 or higher)**

Hardware video acceleration is only enabled if you are using the binaries from ATI, either install them using the `Additional Driver` tool or manually from the ATI site, the last method is preferred since the current package in the `Additional Driver` tool is quite buggy.

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu) contains all the information needed to install/switch/remove drivers for ATI cards.

After this is done you still need a way to connect the media player to the hardware acceleration feature present in your new drivers.

To do that by installing `xvba-va-driver`, `libva-glx1` and `vainfo`. Open a terminal and use this command, or look for the packages using the Ubuntu Software Center

```
sudo apt-get install xvba-va-driver libva-glx1 vainfo
```

After the packages are installed open a terminal (if not using it) and type `vainfo`, you should get an output like the following

```
 libva: libva version 0.32.0
 Xlib:  extension "XFree86-DRI" missing on display ":0.0".
 libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
 libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/fglrx_drv_video.so
 libva: va_openDriver() returns 0
 vainfo: VA API version: 0.32
 vainfo: Driver version: Splitted-Desktop Systems XvBA backend for VA-API - 0.7.8
 vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
 VAProfileH264High               :  VAEntrypointVLD
 VAProfileVC1Advanced            :  VAEntrypointVLD
```

If not something is wrong (drop a comment for more help).

If you get a similar output your drivers are installed and any video player with hardware decoding capabilities should pick it up automatically or allow you to enable this in the player's settings.

For a list of player capable of using hardware video decoding have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VaAPI#Software_supporting_VA_API), the list is not as complete as I wanted but its a good starting point for information.

Comment: Nice instructions; got a [followup question here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125513/choppy-video-in-vlc-even-with-hardware-acceleration-on-ati-radeon-hd-6900). Also wondering why/whether `libva-glx1` is necessary.

Comment: @l0b0: That depends on the media player you're using. For example, `mplayer-vaapi` requires `libva-glx1`. You don't have to specify it though, as it gets installed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

On top of Bruno's suggestion (which worked for me) you may also need to do the following:

1. Add the following lines to your /etc/environment (and reboot):

   LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=xvba
   LIBVA_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib/va/drivers
2. Then to test, run vlc from the command line as follows:

   vlc --ffmpeg-hw
3. Also 'Preferences -> Show Settings ALL -> Input / Codecs -> Video Codecs -> FFmpeg -> Hardware Decoding' TICK! (same as the above, but permanent - can be set from .config/vlc as well).

See: http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_VAAPI

Comment: First half seems to be invalid.
There is no /usr/lib/va/drivers on my system even if I installed the above packages.

Answer (score -1):

I can only help, if you have an ATI/ADM card. In this case:

Do you use the ATI-Driver? You can install it using the System-Settings. There should be an icon called "Additional Drivers". After a reboot, you should be able to use all your graphics-power.

I have an HD5770 and first was not able to install this driver on my 11.10. The auto-updater showed me some updates, and after installing them, it worked well. Maybe this information is relevant for you, too.

If it doesn't work, then try this: 
http://mrrichard.hubpages.com/hub/2-Ways-to-Install-FGLRX-in-Ubuntu-1110-Oneric