# How do I get VA-API and XVBA to work?

Tags: ati, radeon, xbmc, vaapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I enable hardware acceleration for an ATI Radeon HD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87395/how-can-i-enable-hardware-acceleration-for-an-ati-radeon-hd)

I have a Radeon HD 6310 in a [mini-ITX](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157247) motherboard that I am trying to use for a HTPC. I need to figure out how to get [VA-API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Acceleration_API) and [XVBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Video_Bitstream_Acceleration) to work so my ATI card can do all the heavy lifting and I can once again watch 720p/1080p content.

I'd like to use xbmc as the front end, but I could probably code something that could work with VLC.

To clarify, I am interested in how to get a media player to use the hardware acceleration, which the answer in the comments does not address.

Comment: I had seen that and have followed it however I had only limited success and still have no guarantee that the particular players I have available know how to use it.

Comment: Xbmc detects and uses hardware decoding out of the box, if `vainfo` tells you that va is running then do not worry.

Comment: you should try `xbmc-xvba` from the wsnipex ppa, it will install all the needed stuff automatically. If you want the true htpc experience, there is an extensive guide here: http://youresuchageek.blogspot.nl/2012/06/xbmc-install-and-config-howto-for-linux.html