# How can I enable hardware acceleration for an ATI Radeon HD5450

Tags: 11.10, ati

i have followed the steps from the links
[Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu)
and 
[How can I enable hardware acceleration for an ATI Radeon HD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87395/how-can-i-enable-hardware-acceleration-for-an-ati-radeon-hd)

my vainfo output is

```
libva: libva version 0.32.0

Xlib:  extension "XFree86-DRI" missing on display ":0.0".

libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0

libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/fglrx_drv_video.so

libva: va_openDriver() returns 0

vainfo: VA API version: 0.32

vainfo: Driver version: Splitted-Desktop Systems XvBA backend for VA-API - 0.7.8

vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints

      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD

      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
```

which is the same as in the post above but i have choppy video even playing 720p.
Graghics in System info display this

```
Driver VESA:PARK
Experience Standard
```

[image]
[image]

The output of `sudo glxinfo | grep -i direct` is:

```
direct rendering: Yes 
GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_AMD_name_gen_delete, 
GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
GL_EXT_copy_buffer, GL_EXT_copy_texture, 
GL_EXT_direct_state_access,
```

The output of `sudo lspci | grep VGA` is:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Manhattan [Mobility Radeon HD 5430 Series]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-1-x86.x86_64.run
sh amd-driver-installer-12-1-x86.x86_64.run
```

Then choose to build package for your detected distribution. Then you can install the .deb package with

```
sudo dpkg -i fglrx_8.930-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb fglrx-amdcccle_8.930-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb fglrx-dev_8.930-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```