# Are there better FGLRX drivers?

Tags: drivers, radeon, fglrx

I have a Radeon HD 4770, the problem is that when I install the FGLRX drivers my computer becomes laggy as hell. Without them installed I can watch HD video(better than in windows with its official drivers actually), flash works fine and my UI is fast as. But when they are install HD video goes down to about 5 fps, flash is slow and audio is out of sync and my UI is laggy.

The only problem with not having the FGLRX drivers installed is I can't get true 3D games to work. Stuff my core 2 duo can handle run fine but the games that really require a punch get about 2 fps.

I did a bit of reading and heard that others have the same problem but also that it has not always been the case and some have found a way to install an older version of the drivers that runs fine. So my question is are there any better FGLRX drivers?

Answer (score 1):

You might try installing the xvba-va-driver and libva-glx1 packages alongside FGLRX. These allow the computer to offload parts of HD video playback to the GPU. Use vainfo to check if they installed correctly and that your hardware supports offloading.

This is what I used to reduce CPU usage during playback.

Credit to Bruno Pereira's post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87395/how-can-i-enable-hardware-acceleration-for-an-ati-radeon-hd), which helped me.