# Black screen after removing ATI drivers, how do I reinstall?

Tags: boot, kernel, amd-graphics

Well the updated ATI just came out so I tried to install it.  I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Restarted the computer.

I select Ubuntu from GRUB and I get a black screen.  I have no idea how to repair this. I previously followed the same instruction for ATI Drivers 11.10 and 11.11 without a problem.

How do I fix this issue so I can boot into Ubuntu and complete the driver installation process?

Comment: did you download the official driver from the ati website? what version of ubuntu are you running? what is your graphics card?

Answer (score 1):

Reboot into recovery mode, in low graphics mode. Then reinstall your ATI driver:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial.
```

If you see nothing again on the reboot, go back into low graphics mode to uninstall the driver.

Comment: How to reboot into recovery mode, in low graphics...

Comment: Here is the link to the wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: Many thanks, I will try this later or tomorrow.  ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, the most I was able to get was a purple screen with 'Ubuntu" for a split second and then and blank screen again.  This is a dual boot machine with Windows 7.  Are the instructions different?

Comment: Nope. You must make sure you un-install the old driver first.

Comment: Now I'm lost, I thought I did that.  Did it before with the above-referenced instructions.  How do I proceed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1985/discussion-between-chazdg-and-bioshark)

Comment: Try this 2 links with instructions: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide and http://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu  I have to go now, it's 2 a.m. here :)

Comment: I would like to chat with you but, Chrome doesn't seem to want to login to StackExchange...

Comment: I have no idea how to proceed.  The two links provided don't help me get into Recovery mode.

Comment: Ok further details, I changed "quiet splash" to nomodeset and hit Ctrl + X.  System started to boot until I came upon Starting load fallback graphic - (fail).  Everything stopped so I hit ctrl + alt + F1 and it continued a bit  more before freezing for good.  That is where I am.  By the way, I  think I deleted part of this discussion :(

Comment: I guess there is no fix for this issue.  I'm willing and able if somebody can help...:)

Comment: Did you try the link I sent you regarding how to enter into recovery mode: wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode?

Comment: yes indeed I did, but once in recovery mode, I am frozen.  More importantly, there is no low graphics option or any option as the screen is frozen with 4 options.

Comment: I would suggest booting from the live cd and access terminal there. Or in the worst case make a back-up of your home from there, and re-install ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot from Ubuntu Live CD and continue trying Ubuntu 11.10
2. Chroot into your installation:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt && \
   sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev && \
   sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc && \
   sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys && \
   sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts && \
   sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf && \
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```

   where `/dev/sdaX` is the root partition.
3. Install the ati drivers normally
4. Reboot!