# GNOME Shell lags heavily when using the notification area in the activities overview

Tags: 11.10, gnome, ati, fglrx

I am using Catalyst version 11.12 from AMD's website. I have enabled Tear free desktop.
When I try to use gnome shell, everything works fine, until I use an app that uses the notification area in the activities overview (ex: Desura) Gnome shell starts to lag heavily and sometimes crash/restart (shell and windows disappear for 2 seconds then comeback). Anyone have a fix?

Comment: @j-johan-edwars
The bug would be in AMD's driver. Fglrx has had serious issues with gnome shell. A few versions ago it had such severe graphical corruption you could not use gnome-shell. I was asking is there any setting I could change that would fix this, if there isn't all I can do is wait for a new driver (or get a nvidia card, which I will in the future, no more AMD for me).
See: http://ati.cchtml.com/show_bug.cgi?id=99

http://ati.cchtml.com/show_bug.cgi?id=99

Answer (score 2):

Apparently AMD confirmed that the [bug is gone](http://ati.cchtml.com/show_bug.cgi?id=99#c182) with the release of 12.1.

Please refer to this question to remove this and install the newest version.

- [Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu)

If the problem maintains this should be reported to AMD as a new bug for the new driver version, I do not believe there us much you can further do.