# Is it better to use the Ubuntu supplied ATI drivers or the drivers direct from AMD?

Tags: ati

I have a ATI Radeon HD 6300 graphics card, and I'm wondering if it is better for me to use the drivers available via `Additional Drivers` or if I should download and install the [driver direct from AMD](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current ATI drivers present on the Ubuntu repos are buggy and have performance issues.

11.8 will run Unity poorly and will refuse to run Gnome Shell and 11.9 will not be much better in terms of performance and will run Gnome Shell poorly.

I strongly recommend installing any of the ATI driver from version 11.10 up.

There is a post that explains how to install, remove and restore drivers.

- [Install, remove, restore ATI drivers in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu)

Since your card is on the supported hardware list I see no reason why you should be running the outdated drivers in the repos.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you will get a variety of opinions.

My advice would be to try the drivers available via `Additional Drivers` first as if nothing else they will be easier to maintain.

If they do not work for you for some reason, you can try the Direct Driver. Check the "Unofficial Wiki" for hardware compatibility and Ubuntu specific information

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I have chosen from the Additional Driver, because it is well tested via canonical, so there won't be any problems.