# ATI Radeon 9250 Driver Problem

Tags: drivers, ati, installation, radeon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu)

I have a ATI Radeon 9250 video card (250mb) and is a PCI-Express slot. My problem is I don't have the video driver install on my ubuntu 11.10 (32, non-64), I try to install the video card driver, but I didn't, I thing the problem is the driver, because I see that driver only work on a 64bit OS (or maybe my bad English it show me that).

Well, I need some help to know if I did not do something rite (to install the driver correctly), because I'm a little new on Ubuntu and I don't want go back to Windows only for this driver.

P.S.: I don't know if is possible to contact the AMD support or Ubuntu Support, to report this problems, maybe they can fix the problem making a new driver for this device.

Comment: ATI Radeon 9250 is not supported by the ATI vendor drivers for linux anymore. You should instead stick to the radeon driver. Can you install it using the command sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-radeon After that please look if you have an /etc/X11/xorg.conf file and if so, please edit your initial posting and add the complete content of this file.

Comment: PCI-Express? No way! 9250 came to AGP and PCI only. I think you have the PCI version. There is no support for that. But the opensource driver will work.