# Radeon 9200 and Unity problems after adding xorg-edgers PPA

Tags: ati, radeon

I though that doing:

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

It will fix my really SLOW interface using Unity in Oneiric...

Now, where I found this "solution", says that if something goes wrong I would have to put:

sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers

But after that console says

sudo: ppa-purge: command not found

And if I have no solution for this, what would you recommend me to use for a faster interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to install ppa-purge if it hasn't already been installed:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

The usual syntax to use this is

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:[foo]
```

where [foo] is the PPA to remove.

Thus for the xorg-edgers PPA you should use

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

As to your general graphical issues with edgers - you should read their [front-page](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa)

It makes it clear that the PPA is highly unstable.

Some people have found that installing the proprietary drivers resolves slow/laggy windows.  If you want help with this look for a question with the model of your graphics card - and if you cannot find one, create another question.

One of the comments in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95102/ati-radeon-9250-driver-problem) (slightly newer version of your 9200) - if correct - indicates that you might have to stick with the opensource drivers that are installed by default.

If this is the case - using Unity 2D (logout and change the session) might be a better bet to resolve your laggy graphics issues.

To find the exact model name of your graphics card - in a terminal type:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```