# Hybrid graphics - MSI FX420

Tags: ati, hybrid-graphics

I have a MSI FX420 with Intel HD Graphics 3000 and HD Radeon 6470M. on Windows I can switch the card, but on Ubuntu I think it only runs on Radeon and drain all the battery.
is there a way to possible disable the Radeon and use only the Intel HD on Ubuntu?

if you need any more information, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can see these references for Hybrid graphics :
Ubuntu supports hybrid graphics by means of the `vga_switcheroo flag`

```
Enabling vga_switcheroo
```

Further links :

http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/24483-Switchable-Graphics-Ubuntu-10-10

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

[Switching from integrated Nvidia to a Radeon card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105199/switching-from-integrated-nvidia-to-a-radeon-card)

Comment: It might be useful to consolidate the information and include the essential steps here.