# Switching from Nvidia to Radeon graphics card in year 2015

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, ati

I am going to switch my monitors from an Nvidia graphics card to a Radeon Saphire FLEX series 250x ([specifically, this model](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JJJW4OS)).

How should I prepare my 14.04 system so that it simply works once the card is installed? you will forgive me for not acting by answers from [circa 2012 here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105199/switching-from-integrated-nvidia-to-a-radeon-card) because drivers and hardware have come a long way since. It would be wiser for me to act in preparation mode rather than in fire fighting mode.

What might be the series of steps to take for (1) preparing my system, and for (2) making the transition in the OS?

Comment: You should be able to just plug and play.

Comment: Are you sure that card is supported?

Comment: @Zacharee1 its not as easy as PnP. You need to reconfigure graphic driver then display manager. New ati should be working with fglrx proprietary driver.

Comment: @Zacharee1 not from a nVidia - different drivers etc

Comment: @AizuddinZali yeah that makes sense.

Comment: @tim good point, I somehow didn't even check that. Where might that be determined??

Comment: @matt well I cant't see it on the listed supported cards on the wiki - and it's no longer manufactured afaik...

Comment: @Tim, which wiki? [here I see drivers for the r7 200 series](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux) (of which 250x is part according to what I see in the [Saphire offical website](http://www.sapphiretech.com/productdetial.asp?pid=63E4AD88-F755-484B-B594-64CCD763FD4B&lang=eng))

Comment: @matt https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver#Fully_Supported

Comment: The list is not exhaustive so not sure what to make of it. Sometimes I miss Microsoft Windows...

Answer (score -1):

install fglrx driver using terminal commands

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Comment: You shall not post an answer referring to other link.

Comment: new to askubuntu..just trying to help..sorry man...@ Aizuddin Zali

Comment: Its ok, try to improve the answer then you`ll have up vote from me

Comment: That wiki page is a bit perplexing: 
Quote: "If you are switching from another OEM's hardware, NVIDIA for instance, you must uninstall the driver for that hardware before installing the AMD driver." doesn't that leave you headless???!? :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.