# How can I uninstall Graphics driver?

Tags: drivers, graphics, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu)

I want to un-install Graphics driver but I do not know how. 
I downloaded AMD Catalyst™ 11.11 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver .run file from support.AMD.com and installed it manually.

Now, I can't find how to un-install it

*edit1

i enter "sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh" in terminal and in next line it asks me for password. and i can't type, everything i type don't appear in terminal

*edit2

turns out that password can be typed in but cursor is not moving as you type it and that fooled me.

Comment: Hey @ubi, I have linked the instructions to remove and revert to the open source driver, they should work the same, if those dont work please flag this to a moderator to re open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you installed using the script, you will have the file fglrx-uninstall.sh for uninstalling the ATI drivers.

To do that, run "sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh" in a terminal.

When done, run "fglrxinfo" from a terminal and it should say it's not installed.

Comment: i do that and there is problem, i enter "sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh" in terminal and in next line it asks me for password. and i can't type, everything i type don't appear in terminal

Comment: edit your question to include the results

Comment: once a command is given in terminal, you need to wait until it returns again with the prompt or you killed the process during which time it didn't complete. You are not able to TYPE again in the terminal while it is working. TRY IT AGAIN, this time wait a little while before doing anything else. Have some patience.

Comment: oh ok i'll report back

Comment: this time i waited 5-6 minutes and tried to type in password but still, i can't type in terminal

Comment: is it possible to find usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh manually and uninstall it that way?

Comment: Does it beep or just not display anything at the password prompt? Usually, your password won't be displayed when you enter it.

Comment: suggest another approach,did you look at the AMD web site for directions

Comment: i managed to uninstall it using terminal, turns out that password can be typed in but cursor is not moving as you type it and that fooled me, thank you very much.

Comment: good. take care

Comment: @ubi Yeah, when you type `sudo` you need to enter the root password, this will not be shown