# Has any one tried ATI 12.2 Proprietary Display Driver for Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit?

Tags: 11.10, ati, graphics

I have ATI Technologies Inc Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series graphic card. Was using Open source drivers and are decent. Hangs little bit sometimes but are fine most of the time

Recently, I have seen ATI released 12.2 drivers. Has any one tried them ? Are they working fine ? Can I try them ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu same information is valid for the AMD 12.02 drivers

Answer (score 1):

I'm using gnome-shell and I had installed 12.1 drivers working well. I updated to 12.2 yesterday. I had to downgrade this morning to 12.1 again because everything wents very slow.
My system was slow/sluggish, cpu was always high with 100% peeks as Freaky said.

I'm not happy with this new version :/

**UPDATED: 2012-03-16**

Seems that my problems were because the dual monitor configuration. After disabled one monitor everything went smooth again (as 12.1).

Comment: Which is better 12.1 drivers or open source drivers?

Comment: I traditionally installed proprietary drivers because I played some 3d games (only playables with these drivers).
I waited for the 12.1 to use gnome-shell because with the previous releases was not ready for gnome-shell. Then in this case you could consider open source better.
If your graphic card is prior to directx version 10 (more or less) then it is not supported by proprietary drivers (another point for open source ones).

I'm not sure but when I choose to install the proprietary drivers I did it because I wanted to connect my monitor with hdmi and it was not supported by open source.

Comment: I only wanted to show that it depends in what is better to you. There're a lot of factors to take this choice :)

Comment: Yesterday I tried the open source drivers with my Ati 5650 and It worked worst than the propietary drivers (at least for my graphic card). On loading X the screen show noise, after login it take a lot to load the desktop, later everything went smooth but with the fan working hard(later stop), after load some applications(chrome was a good one) all went sluggish. I also tried some optimizations in xorg and ccsm but nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

You can install them following the instructions found here

```
http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide
```

Read the guide carefully, and it will go OK.

If anything breaks, most possibly you will not get any graphics, be sure to write down the necessary commands to return to the original state. Just hit `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` to switch to a command line and enter the commands.

It has happened to me before, but removing the drivers and returning to the open source ones fixed it. However, generally the proprietary drivers are faster and support better 3d performance.

The GUI installer found on ATI site never worked for me so I do not recommend it. The above method worked every time.

Answer (score 0):

Running swell here on my ASUS 1015-B netbook with hybrid AMD graphics. Things are much smoother now with Ubuntu 11.10 64, especially Unity and full screen movies with VLC 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm using amd-driver-installer-12-1-x86.x86_64 on ubuntu 11.10 x64. after some tweaks found on the net for compiz and so it's OK.

Comment: Did you notice any difference between open source drivers and proprietary drivers?

Comment: I haven't tried the open source drivers

Answer (score -1):

Whow, things horribly suck for me (I'm on gentoo though). gnome-sell consumes 8% CPU by default, bouncing a simple gnome terminal up and down gets it to 100% easily.

Once again a fantastic release from AMD/Ati, I knew I should have gotten a nVidia card.