# Ubuntu 11.10 ati x1300 3d support?

Tags: 11.10, ati, 3d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu)

I have acer aspire 5100 and graphic card ati x1300.My graphic card supports 3D but ubuntu doesn't.I researched a lot but i didn't understand them.Also i followed the instruction below but it didn't worked either.

[Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu)

It says:

"aticonfig: No supported adapters detected"

after

"sudo aticonfig --initial -f" command.

English is not my native language and I don't know much about Ubuntu.Can someone explain it simply?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [supported hardware](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware) table the ATI driver you should be using is already installed and used by default in Ubuntu 11.10.

Your card, the ATI X1300 uses the RV505 chipset, which according to the table, is supported by the catalyst legacy or open-source drivers.

Since the first cannot be installed in Ubuntu 11.10 unless you are able to install and use a kernel version 2.6.28 (or earlier) you are only able to use the second and that is already installed in your system.