# Help with migrating from Widows, x64 FGLRX, CPU load, Java and Minecraft

Tags: 11.10, java, fglrx, oracle

I'm new to Ubuntu, it is the second time I have installed it. This comp is Dell studio 1558. Some specs: CPU- Intel core i7 Q720 1. 6GHz, GPU- ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5400

FGLRX- I've fallowed [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu) among inspecting many others, I have tried all of the variants mentioned in that tread before reverting back to the drivers supplied with Ubuntu ( through additional drivers ) which apparently seem to work best.

I am testing them with minecraft as silly as it may sound. In 2 to 60 minutes the FPS drop from 70+ to somewhere between 0 and 5. While "fgl_glxgears" runs at between 400 and 800 FPS smoothly.

I am using Oracle ( sun ) JRE6 to run minecraft, I have gotten it through a tutorial linked on Oracle's website, I currently have no other version of java installed ( was worse when I had a few others here ). After closing the game Ubuntu is similarly slow, I've checked the CPU load using System Monitor and it shows one of the CPU's jumping to 80%~100% load at a time. A reboot solves it.

I realize my mess is up to me to solve but a hand is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Run `ps -ef > before` then `ps -ef > whilst` while it runs and then `ps -ef > after` after closing. Finally upload the files
`before whilst after`