# Can my Radeon X1600 graphics card run 3d games on 11.10

Tags: 11.10, radeon

I have a PC with Ubuntu 11.10 and an Intel core2 duo processor. I love Ubuntu but have one big issue,which is in my question.

My Radeon X1600 graphics card wont run any form of 3d, games,unity 3d,nothing.

It worked fine with my old OS (Windows Xp) so I think it must be the drivers. Does anyone know how to enable 3D for this card or install a driver that will run 3D.

I am new to Ubuntu, so clear and simple explanations please with as little jargon as possible.

Comment: check this first http://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 11.10 (*and any other recent distribution that uses an updated kernel*) [you can only use the open source drivers](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware), and those are already included and activated when you install Ubuntu.

To use an old version of the Catalyst fglrx drivers you need to be running a 2.6.28 kernel or lower. You cannot do that using Ubuntu 11.10.

There is not much you can do about drivers with your card. The open source drivers should be enough and suffice to run most of the actual software that it can run without suffering performance issues.

It's an old card, it will be hard to make it run any recent advanced 3D software, with or with out proprietary drivers.