# How can I install the ATI video card driver for Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: installation, ati

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu)

How can I install the ATI video card driver for Ubuntu 11.10?

Can someone please help me?

Comment: duplicate.  before you post questions, try the search box

Answer (score 0):

The best driver, Gallium 3D, should automatically be enabled and installed.

Try running a 3D game like Neverball or Neverputt, you can find both in Ubuntu Software Center.

If they don't work install fglrx (not the post-release update) with Additional Drivers in System Settings.

[image: screenshoot]

Comment: [...]if they don't work install fglrx form the *AMD site* [...] which is the newest one,

Answer (score 0):

This steps worked for me and what you probabably should do is upgrade you ATI drivers. They have solved a lot of those issues you're facing on.

http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/12/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-1112-linux.html

> For smooth installation, it is recommended to uninstall currently
>   available Catalyst driver. To do this, use these commands from the
>   terminal:
>
> `sudo apt-get remove fglrx*`
>
> To install the AMD Catalyst 11.12 Linux driver now on Ubuntu 11.10
>   (32-bit & 64-bit) or any older version, run this sequence of commands:
>
> `cd ~/; mkdir catalyst11.12; cd catalyst11.12/`
>
> `wget -O ati-driver-installer-11-12.run http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ati-driver-installer-11-12-x86.x86_64.run`
>
> If you have a 64 bit system, then install this before anything
>
> `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`
>
> After that you can start installing the new ati driver:
>
> `chmod +x ati-driver-installer-11-12.run`
>
> `sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-12.run`
>
> Make now an update for the X.org file with this command:
>
> `sudo aticonfig --initial -f`
>   `sudo reboot`