# No graphics after installing AMD Catalyst 12.4 and installing the recommended updates afterwards

Tags: graphics, updates, update-manager, radeon, catalyst

Some days ago, I installed Ubuntu 12.04. Since I wanted to use dualview using an external display I installed the propriatary AMD Catalyst 12.4.
The graphics are fine, but if I run the updates found by the updates manager, Ubuntu won't be able to start with graphics after reboot.
I installed Ubuntu 3 times until I realized what the problem was.
So now I got the basic installation with Catalyst running but I can't update the system.
Is there any solution to this? Or can I somehow identify which update causes this?

My System is a Lenovo y560 Ideapad (Intel Core i7, 8GB RAM, with AMD Radeon HD 6570M/5700 Series.

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you add any ppa that provide amd driver? like `xorg-edgers`

Comment: Did you manually install the drivers from ATI or did you install them via `apt-get`?

Comment: I downloaded "amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run" from their website and run this installer. That seemed to work pretty fine.

Comment: Ifound out, that if I had installed the updates first, a driver gets installed which is able to manage dual view without catalyst. Is it possible to uninstall the catalyst drivers safely? Then I could simply run the updates and set up my screen. It took me days to set up the computer with all programs so I can't risk loosing anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the risk of uninstalling Catalyst using [the procedure described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu).

After Catalyst had been removed, I could install all the upcoming updates. The open source drivers handle the graphics card with dual view very well.

Answer (score 0):

For any `Graphics issue` with ati drives- purge the open source `fglrx driver` and install the `proprietary driver` off their website.

For some reason i faced the exact same issue with ati driver when the `janitor` tool within `Ubuntu tweak tool` deleted my fglrx driver

Comment: No driver called `fglrx` is open source. There is an open source driver, and there is `fglrx` as provided by Ubuntu's repositories, and there is the `fglrx` driver as provided by the upstream (ATi/AMD) website. But `fglrx` is the name of the *proprietary* ATi/AMD video driver.

Comment: but the one in the repo(archive) is also called fglrx ?isnt it ?

Comment: There are multiple drivers for ATi in official repositories. [`fglrx`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/fglrx) is provided in the [Restricted component](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) (the Restricted component provides non-free drivers).