# Dual Screen will only mirror after 12.04 upgrade

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors

I have been using Ubuntu with a dual screen for years now, after upgrading to 12.04 LTS i cannot get my dual screen working properly

Graphics:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV350 AR [Radeon 9600]
01:00.1 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV350 AR [Radeon 9600] (Secondary)
```

I noticed i was using open source drivers and attempted to install official binaries using the methods in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu) thread.

Output:

```
liam@liam-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 45.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 739 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/restricted fglrx i386 2:8.960-0ubuntu1 [39.2 MB]
Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/restricted fglrx-amdcccle i386 2:8.960-0ubuntu1 [5,883 kB]                                          
Fetched 45.1 MB in 1min 33s (484 kB/s)                                                                                                                 
(Reading database ... 328081 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace fglrx 2:8.951-0ubuntu1 (using .../fglrx_2%3a8.960-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Error! There are no instances of module: fglrx
8.951 located in the DKMS tree.
Done.
Unpacking replacement fglrx ...
Preparing to replace fglrx-amdcccle 2:8.951-0ubuntu1 (using .../fglrx-amdcccle_2%3a8.960-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement fglrx-amdcccle ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up fglrx (2:8.960-0ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf because link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libaticalcl.so because associated file /usr/lib32/fglrx/libaticalcl.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libaticalrt.so because associated file /usr/lib32/fglrx/libaticalrt.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf because link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libaticalcl.so because associated file /usr/lib32/fglrx/libaticalcl.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libaticalrt.so because associated file /usr/lib32/fglrx/libaticalrt.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-25-generic-pae
Loading new fglrx-8.960 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.2.0-25-generic-pae
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 3.2.0-25-generic-pae
Done.

fglrx:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.2.0-25-generic-pae/updates/dkms/

depmod.......

DKMS: install completed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Setting up fglrx-amdcccle (2:8.960-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-25-generic-pae
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
liam@liam-desktop:~$ sudo aticonfig --initial -f
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected
```

When i attempt to get my settings back to what they were before upgrading i get this message

```
requested position/size for CRTC 81 is outside the allowed limit: position=(1440, 0), size=(1440, 900), maximum=(1680, 1680)
```

and

```
GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._gnome_2drr_2derror_2dquark.Code3: requested position/size for CRTC 81 is outside the allowed limit: position=(1440, 0), size=(1440, 900), maximum=(1680, 1680)
```

Any idea's on what i need to do to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using the proprietary AMD control panel (amd-cccle I think) rather than the Gnome/Ubuntu Display Settings panel?

Comment: Just using the Ubuntu Display settings, couldn't get any proprietary stuff to work as the driver doesn't seem to install properly.

Answer (score 0):

Dual monitor support is buggy in Ubuntu 12.04 with ati gfx cards. Now I am not sure if this is because of ubuntu or its due to propriety amd drivers. Anyways I am on dual monitor setup as well and I managed to get multiple monitors working by reinstalling ATI catalyst drivers.

First remove your existing Catalyst/fglrx drivers

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

Than try installing your drivers manually by following steps mentioned [here](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29).