# Wubi Lubuntu 12.10 Splash Screen upon Boot

Tags: wubi, lubuntu

I recently installed Wubi with Lubuntu on my Windows PC. Installation went very well. However, reboot didn't work so well.

Everytime I boot, I can get up to the splash screen with the dots, and then it just hangs. I've tried nomodeset, and other stuff, but just doesn't seem to work.

Please help me, and you might need to explain things in excess, as I'm a complete newb.

Thank you!

Spec:
Compaq Presario CQ43-310AU
16 GHz 2 CPU
2GB RAM
AMD Radeon HD 6320 Graphics

Comment: Please add your machine specs (brand, model, graphics card(s), etc.) to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried booting in recovery mode? Select advanced options, and then the second entry. If that works to get to the recovery menu, select Resume normal boot. Report back on what happens. PS if you can't see the Grub menu, hold down the SHIFT key after selecting Lubuntu.

Comment: Oh gosh! Resume boot works! But why doesn't it work normally?

Comment: It works because it uses `nomodeset`. How were you using it before? Now that it's booted see if you can install a driver for your graphics card. Check this out: http://askubuntu.com/q/74171/14916

Answer (score 0):

Remove `quit splash` in Grub config, `/etc/default/grub`.

Change

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`

Restart Grub to apply the configuration: `update-grub`.