# New video card stops at Ubuntu startup screen

Tags: drivers, video, amd-graphics

I have removed an older Nvidia card and put a AMI HD4550-based card into a Ubuntu machine running 11.10. I ran the Nvidia uninstall script and then have followed that by using the steps in [Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu/74172#74172) to install the `fglrx` packages. Namely:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

However, when I now restart the system, after the BIOS screen, the 'Ubuntu' screen with the red dots appears...and goes no further. It simply hangs there although the system can be ssh'ed to.

I'm not fussy and just want the card to run the console so any drivers will work - open source or not.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current-updates
```

I then went and deleted `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (which appeared to have been generated by the Nvidia install) and restarted the machine.

System came up with a base working GUI. Yay!