# Why does Aircrack-ng 1.1 in Ubuntu 13.04 stop my graphic card from working?

Tags: 13.04, graphics, aircrack-ng

When I use `airmon-ng` in the terminal, my graphic card stops working properly and a fuzzy screen appears, making me go for a hard reboot. I use v. 1.1 of Aircrack-ng in Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 on Intel i3 M350

Comment: Have you installed any drivers?

Comment: No, I haven't. Everything seems perfect otherwise, so i thought i didn't need to. How can i find the most proper driver for my graphics card?

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu