# Export Ubuntu to a pendrive

Tags: 12.10, wubi, usb-drive

how can I make an exact copy (like migration) of my Ubuntu 12.10 (I installed it through Wubi) in a capable pendrive (like 32 gb)? That would be useful in future since I could also remove Wubi and keep my Ubuntu usable on other PCs.

And another question, if I do this, there is a possibility to upgrade in future without losing applications or data?

Comment: did you tried Remastersys for making a live ubuntu from what ever you have in your installed ubuntu ?

Comment: bcbc is the same thing for doing it onto a USB drive?
mohamed remastersys seems to be very old, does it support Ubuntu 12.x or more?

Comment: @anonymous yes, you just create the target partition(s) the same as you would on any drive, and migrate to it. It will install `grub` on the USB, and then you could boot it from any computer* (*make sure you don't install a closed source graphics driver and then boot it on a computer with a different graphics card).

Comment: @anonymous PS the migration script works on normal installs as well, so you can later migrate from the USB back to an internal hard drive.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I have another question as yet since your advice. My closed source graphics driver - as Ubuntu says - is actived but not currently in use. What does that mean? Can it be problematic on other computers if it isn't in use? How can I perform it?

Comment: What graphics driver is it? Or, if you're not sure, what graphics card do you have? PS use @bcbc to catch my attention.

Comment: @bcbc I have AMD Radeon HD 6570. Drivers are powered by AMD Catalyst Center. As far as I know for most graphic cards open-drivers are much less power than closed-source drivers.

Comment: See here (look for *Revert back to the open source drivers*) to remove the drivers: http://askubuntu.com/a/74172/14916

Comment: Do I seriously need all that stuff? Settings window uses to work as well for enabling/disabling closed-source drivers