# how to install AMD Catalyst or AMD Graphic Drivers and other drivers in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, drivers, ati, performance, battery

I recently purchased an HP laptop (Intel-AMD Hybrid). I successfully installed Ubuntu 13.04 on it.

But my battery is draining quite quickly. It hardly works for 30-50 minutes. I guess it might be due to the graphics driver.

Could anyone please suggest how to install below, recommended settings to increase battery life and performance of my laptop:

1. AMD Driver / AMD Catalyst for AMD HD Raedon 5400
2. Synaptics Touch pad driver
3. IDT High Definition Audio Driver

Answer (score 0):

check: [Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu/74172#74172)

or http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Main_Page