# Graphics Card driver issues, ATI, Radeon HD 4200

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I have had a major issue once I installed Ubuntu 13.10. I noticed that my performance was slow and it appeared to me that I needed to install my drivers. So as most people do I go look for a quick, easy, and fast, solution. So I came here and after reading around they said to type a few things in the terminal, and also looking around I noticed a lot of people say "Go look in system settings and look for the Additional Drivers tab and all of your drivers should be all waiting for you on a silver platter waiting to update." I went to this magical place they spoke of and it showed that "No additional Drivers are available." So I go and look on the askUbuntu and go to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu) link and I did everything for the 64x system to install drivers. And nothing really seemed to be off or anything bad, I actually got really excited because I did not see any errors in the terminal (could just be me being oblivious) So I go and look at my Graphics Card again in the "About This Computer" and it still says I have "Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880, now I know for sure I have a AMD Radeon HD 4200 graphics card, and if Ubuntu is saying that I have some Gallium thing, (This is where I got lost) Do I update the drivers for this Gallium thing that just appeared as my so called graphics card? (Hopefully not) Or do I look for more ways to update my graphics card? Now I have heard a few things about proprietary and open source graphic drivers. Either way guys I am very VERY lost and confused and a tad bit scared, so I would love if you helped me out.

TL;DR Graphics Card Driver = BAD, Send help!

Here are some system information just incase some of you need it.

Memory: 3.6 GiB (I have 4 installed I don’t know why it is showing 3.6)

Processor AMD Phenom(tm) X2 521 Processor × 2 (Maybe the only thing right on this new install of Ubuntu, no offence I love it just I’m confused.)

Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880 (I actually have a ATI Radeon™ HD 4200 Series)

OS type: 64-bit

Disk: 980.4 GB (Again I have one terabyte as my hard drive, I may just be a derp and that is a terabyte in GB's, but I failed to start a new problem for myself by investigating this.)

Since this is my problem and you guys are here to help me out of your own free goodwill then I have the obligation to help you help me, I will give you any information, and I hope to get to the bottom of this. (I never type this much, unless it is an essay, and barely when I have those.)
Also if there is another thread like this then I am very sorry, my forum etiquette is not the best.

Comment: If you run `lspci -v`, what shows up as the Graphics card *(or `VGA compatible controller`)*, and its driver? Also, aslong as it works properly, there might be no need to change anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AMD Ati Radeon HD 4870 Drivers on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/471609/amd-ati-radeon-hd-4870-drivers-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gallium3D is an open source driver for graphic chipsets so there should be nothing wrong if that's what it installed.
Which method did you use to install drivers? i also run a radeonHD and had to install ati proprietary drivers for it to fully work.

Downlaod drivers for your device from [here](http://www.amd.com/it/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-4000/ati-radeon-hd-4200/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-4200-specificatications.aspx)

Follow installation instructions from [here](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Raring_Installation_Guide#Installing_Proprietary_Drivers_a.k.a._Catalyst.2Ffglrx)

Comment: Well i think I have narrowed down he issue, and I think ubuntu is a no go for me, sadly. What happened was that the company AMD made my graphics card drivers a Prosperity driver and they are not releasing updates for linux. SOOO basically AMD is saying "You cant change our code for the community benefit and we refuse to update the drivers for all of our users that use linux" Or something like that. So now I have decided to switch back over.

Comment: you can take your driver back by downgrading to 12.04. That version will have support until 2007.