# AMD Ati Radeon HD 4870 Drivers on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, 14.04, ati, radeon

I have a computer with Ubuntu 14.04 installed and I have a Radeon HD 4870 (RV770) video card and I want to install Ati drivers but when I download it says this:

```
Distro Version entered incorrectly or not supported, use --listpkg to identify valid distro versions
```

The latest drivers in AMD web doesn't mention my graphic card so I don't know if it works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your card is no longer supported by AMD. AMD now only support HD5000 and above with their proprietary driver.

This is the compatibility list from the [release note](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDCatalyst14-4LINReleaseNotes.aspx) of the AMD Catalyst Proprietary Linux Graphic Driver v14.4:

```
Desktop Product Family Compatibility ​
AMD Radeon™ R9 290 Series   AMD Radeon™ HD 8000 Series
AMD Radeon™ R9 280 Series   AMD Radeon™ HD 7000 Series
AMD Radeon™ R9 270 Series   AMD Radeon™ HD 6000 Series
AMD Radeon™ R7 260 Series   ATI Radeon™ HD 5000 Series
AMD Radeon™ R7 250 Series    
AMD Radeon™ R7 240 Series   

All-In-One Desktop Product Family Compatibility ​
AMD Radeon™ HD 7600A Series AMD Radeon™ HD 6600A Series
AMD Radeon™ HD 7450A Series AMD Radeon™ HD 6350A Series

AMD Embedded Product Family Compatibility ​
AMD Radeon™ E6760   AMD Radeon™ E6460

AMD APU Product Family Compatibility ​
Desktop Mobile
AMD Radeon™ HD 8000D Series AMD Radeon™ HD 8000G Series
AMD Radeon™ HD 7000D Series AMD Radeon™ HD 7000G Series
AMD Radeon™ HD 6000D Series AMD Radeon™ HD 6000G Series

AMD Mobility Product Family Compatibility ​
AMD Radeon™ HD 8000M Series AMD Radeon™ HD 6000M Series
AMD Radeon™ HD 7000M Series ATI Mobility Radeon™ HD 5000 Series
```

Also see [AskUbuntu: Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu) and [Launchpad #1058040 fglrx-installer not working with AMD Radeon/Mobility Radeon HD 2000-4000 cards in Quantal](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1058040).

The good news is that your card is now fully supported by the [open source radeon driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver).