# Ubuntu ATI Drivers after installation

Tags: installation

So first step. I go and GRUB menu and set `nomodeset` and test it without instalation.

Everything seems ok. What should I do then? Install Ubuntu?

And after that can't I just go to AMD homepage and download ATI drivers for HD 6570 from their homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a new user of Ubuntu you should **not** have to download anything from anywhere to get almost all running smoothly without issues.

This is especially true for graphics. If there was a bug or any other incompatibility in such brand new and partly untested downloaded drivers they will let you alone with a system booting to a command line terminal only, or in the worst case with a system that can not boot at all. Then it may not be so easy to get rid of these drivers again.

There is a great effort from our community to provide you with almost all possible drivers to make sure your system boots. Amongst these the **Open Source ATI driver** `"radeon"` is very stable, and it is well supported by ATI (ATI engineers develop this driver for us).

Only very new graphic cards, or applications demanding a lot of GPU power may benefit from a newer, proprietary or untested driver. Only if we had issues with our present setup we may consider installing a newer proprietary graphics driver.

> This is not the usual case.

Many people are very happy with the default drivers installed from the installation CD. They would not have much if any benefit from a newer driver.

In your case after you had already seen that your computer runs well in the live system I recommend you just install Ubuntu and enjoy it as it is. Refrain from updating or upgrading things with downloads from the Internet.

> This will very likely break your system sooner or later.

In case you have graphical issues - look around for other people with the same problem to see how they solved it. Then you may consider installing a proprietary driver which is only a mouse click away.

Also see: [Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu)