# Installing AMD Catalyst 13.1 Proprietary Driver on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, ati, 14.04

How can I install AMD Catalyst driver? (first time using ubuntu)

I was told to install `fglrx` but it froze when booting to desktop, so I fixed that issue and uninstalled `fglrx`. I followed [this procedure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu/74172#74172), some commands were outdated/obsolete in addition to the posts being old and for versions before 13.10, I am on ubuntu 14.04. I was given this [link](https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx) and when I get to this part`sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy` it cannot be found. I followed all the steps correctly previous to this part. I tried looking at other questions but they just take me back to these two links, there is the [Ubuntu AMD Catalyst Install](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uaci/) on sourceforge does anyone have experience with it does it work? I'd rather do it myself, but I might try this.

My question is are there any up to date posts that I can follow to install this driver? Or could someone show me how to do it here step by step? Below is my graphics card info

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710 [Radeon HD 4350/4550]
```

Comment: You're trying to install drivers because the default installation didn't worked correctly, right?

Comment: By default installation do you mean fglrx? If so yes it didnt work. If not my graphics card is not supported so it doesn't show up in Software-and-Update. I'm not sure what you mean by default installation this is my first time using ubuntu.

Comment: By default installation I meant the moment zero, when you finished to install Ubuntu and didn't modify the system nor installed drivers by your self. For instance, my graphic card worked perfect with the default installation without install third party drivers.

Comment: No everything worked fine after I first installed ubuntu, I just opened software-center and started installing usual things flash, ubuntu restricted extras, etc. And when I thought about graphics drivers I wasnt sure so I came here. I'm just trying to install the driver nothing is broken or not working.

Comment: Then, **why** would you install a driver? Are you aware that it could break your system?

Comment: So I don't need this driver to play steam games like l4d2 or tf2 and what not?

Comment: If you want to keep going, check [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/286775/62483). You should try that, and if you have *errors*, then edit your post and add useful information (i.e. card model, error outputs)

Comment: Thank you for your help I'm going to try the first link [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/286775/62483), the second link was already given to me before and didn't work for me. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The link in the previous comment is not working for me I updated my question accordingly.