# How to install proprietary ATI/AMD drivers on 14.10?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, 14.10

I just **upgraded to 14.10** from 14.04, and the built-in driver for my **ATI Radeon HD 5450** sorta-kinda works okay because I do get a signal on my monitor, but it lacks any kind of acceleration, making the Dash and the menu reallly slow, and even typing this post has a significant keyboard-to-screen lag. What's more, the built-in drivers don't seem to support screen standby, so the monitor stays on forever :-/

I've tried several*) methods of getting proprietary drivers to work, but they all fail the same way: the boot simply ends at `tty1` instead of going into the graphical mode.

**Is the root cause that no 14.10-compatible driver exist?** Or is there a *"canonical"* method that is proven to work, for ATI, on 14.10? <sub>(pun intended...)</sub>

As far as I understand the matter by now, the problem seems to be that 14.10 uses X server version 1.16 but all the drivers only mention X server 1.15...

[image]

*) Methods I've tried:

- selecting the proprietary choices in the screenshot above,
- http://www.noobslab.com/2013/04/install-ati-amd-catalyst-drivers-in.html,
- [Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu),
- [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx),
- http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Trusty_Installation_Guide (yes, I know this is *trusty* and not *utopic*)

Comment: run `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati` . see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=xserver-xorg-video-ati&searchon=all) version is 1.17

Comment: @DuminduMahawela thank you. *When* should I run that - before or after I install any of the above drivers? Which of my bullets would you recommend? I can't tell the difference.

Comment: It is xserver xorg driver. You dont need to install from the above. just run this in command line.

Comment: Thanks again @DuminduMahawela - why not put this as an answer I can accept? I'll try it out and hope for success :-)

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun Did the upvoted answer fix your issues?

Comment: @DanW thanks for the reminder, but sadly it didn't work for me. What worked was a magic combination of removing various X and ATI components. Now I'm only using Ubuntu built-in material (which curiously _didn't_ work out of the box!).

Answer (score 1):

You can Install **Xserver Xorg** driver in command line. You dont need to install from the Software & Update.

Just run this in command line

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati`

See [here at packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=xserver-xorg-video-ati&searchon=all). Version is 1.17

Answer (score 0):

Well things have changed since the release of Omega driver which have support up to version 1.16 of X. Head to AMD website to download the driver.

Comment: Tried, but didnt work :(