# Distorted graphics resolution after updating quiet splash in Linux boot

Tags: 14.04, grub2, ati, display

I am facing this issue where the graphics resolution on my Laptop has gone worse after Ubuntu install.

The problem crept up after I updated my grub to have a dual boot of Ubuntu and Windows 7. I was faced with a black screen, once I restarted the system.

Research on ask ubuntu pointed me to a solution where you have to replace the `quiet spalsh` with `nomodeset`. I tried that but to no avail. The graphics would still not be corrected. 
I have tried the following as of now

Since my system is an AMD system with ATI Radeon graphics card, so I also tried this

```
radeon.modeset=0
```

But the issue still persisted.

I then tried changing the `GRUB_GFXMODE` line in the grub file to have that match the system resolution which is 1024x768.
But this step has also failed to correct the graphics situation. Am I missing some drivers from the Linux part, because the graphics are perfectly fine if I boot Windows.

System Configuration :

AMD A4 Vision

Dual Core ATI Radeon Graphics 1GB

Windows 7/ Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

4 GB RAM

Comment: this might help http://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu

Comment: I tried the steps mentioned in the thread but to no avail. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after searching a lot on the internet I finally corrected the graphics on my system. 
I came upon a bug filed for Ubuntu 14.04.2, which is the version I am using.

Here is the link to the bug filed :[bug #1424491](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1424491)

Scroll down to comment #24 by Nestor Acevedo. I followed the commands mentioned by him

```
sudo apt-get install libcheese*
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
```

and finally installed the fglrx updates through this command

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

This corrected the graphics distortion on my system.

Comment: it fix my problem too, but it looks like the graphic its little bit low and slow response