# Kubuntu won't boot after installing fglrx-updates

Tags: boot, kubuntu, fglrx, 15.10

I'm having trouble booting kubuntu after installing `fglrx-updates` (or just `fglrx`). I originally was having issue described in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1493888 however the fix for this has recently been released. Even with the update I still can't boot Kubuntu, but
I can get a bit further now (it used to only show "Starting version 219", but Kubuntu still gets stuck while booting and showing "Kubuntu" logo). I do want to use fxglr (for better performance in games and because I'm having random issues with open source driver which although not game breaking are annoying). Is there any way to diagnose and fix that?

`lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2`

```
00:02.0 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0162] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Motherboard [1849:0162]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Curacao XT [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270X/370 OEM] [1002:6810]
    Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Device [174b:e271]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

`dpkg-query -l fglrx*`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                   Version           Architecture Description
+++-======================-=================-============-=========================================================
un  fglrx-amdcccle         <none>            <none>       (no description available)
ii  fglrx-amdcccle-updates 2:15.201-0ubuntu1 amd64        Catalyst Control Center for the AMD graphics accelerators
un  fglrx-control          <none>            <none>       (no description available)
un  fglrx-control-qt2      <none>            <none>       (no description available)
un  fglrx-driver           <none>            <none>       (no description available)
un  fglrx-driver-core      <none>            <none>       (no description available)
un  fglrx-glx              <none>            <none>       (no description available)
ii  fglrx-updates          2:15.201-0ubuntu1 amd64        Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators
ii  fglrx-updates-core     2:15.201-0ubuntu1 amd64        Minimal video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators
```

`/var/log/gpu-manager.log`

```
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
grep dmesg status 256
dmesg status 256 == 0? No
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is fglrx loaded? yes
Was fglrx unloaded? no
Is fglrx blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? yes
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? yes
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? no
Is fglrx kernel module available? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:162
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Is boot vga? no
Vendor/Device Id: 1002:6810
BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver. Skipping...
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Found "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card0: 0
Does it require offloading? no
last cards number = 1
Has amd? no
Has intel? yes
Has nvidia? no
How many cards? 1
Has the system changed? No
main_arch_path x86_64-linux-gnu, other_arch_path i386-linux-gnu
Current alternative: /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf
Current core alternative: /usr/lib/fglrx-core/ld.so.conf
Is nvidia enabled? no
Is fglrx enabled? yes
Is mesa enabled? no
Is pxpress enabled? no
Is prime enabled? no
Is nvidia available? no
Is fglrx available? yes
Is fglrx-core available? yes
Is mesa available? yes
Is pxpress available? yes
Is prime available? no
Single card detected
No change - nothing to do
```

Comment: pls provide information on graphicscard equipment:

`lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2`

Comment: Added lspci info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its stuck like this and u cannot diagnose (which is a pitty) u can still use the recovery-option of the most recent kernel in the GRUB-menu to come to a root-shell. But before that u will have to establish a "network-connection" from within the recovery-menu

Then run there
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

`exit` would return you to the recovery-menu (just said) – would recomend `sudo reboot` then - If I understood yr Q right and you are seeking a way to catch the update. If not so then

Option 2: Another opportunity would be to edit the 1st start-sequence in the GRUB-menu and append the boot-option *nomodeset* If this alone doesn't help insert  *xforcevesa* in addition. Just place these options between *"quiet* *plymouth"* Hope this helps ;-)

edit3:
Something went obviously wrong, in order to find out the right proceeding on installation of proprietary software, you firstly have to revert your system back into a stable state - remove fglrx wt all its components.

Reinstall the missing parts for the opensource driver.

For error analysis it is essential to share information about your systems components in question. Not having this can end up in a time-consuming guess & try + lead to frustration on both sides. It also reduces the risk to get any breakage or malformation.

This answer already given may help you to understand the complexity+necessary steps – https://askubuntu.com/a/74172/472414 (is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Sorry I clarified the question: I do want to use fglrx. I can boot into Kubuntu if I go to recovery mode and `apt-get purge fglrx*`. I tried adding `nomodeset` and `xforcevesa` to grub options with `fglrx-updates` installed (although there was no "quiet plymouth", but I saw "quiet splash" and added it there), however it didn't change anything.

Comment: Once u experienced now u can start thru with the recovery-mode u can now start analyzing: $`/var/log/gpu-manager.log` $`dpkg-query -l fglrx*`

Comment: Sorry I'm not trying to hide information, I just don't know what information is needed. If you need anything else just let me know. In the meantime I looked over `gpu-manager.log` and I noticed an error there. Seems it can't find driver. I tried googling the problem, though it seems there's only one relevant link and even that talks about hybrid graphics which I'm pretty sure I don't have since this is desktop PC and 3650 radeon which is a lot older model and makes sense it's not supported. I've also checked the link you provided, didn't help much and compatibility list seems outdated.

Comment: Thanks for providing the relevant information. From the above given link (is my ati-graphics-card supported in Ubuntu) -> [http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware#Older_RadeonHD_.28Catalyst_Legacy_13.1_.26_Open_Source.29] Sorry to say so, AMD stopped supporting older graphics cards with FGLRX a while ago. U need to rely in the OpenSource Driver RADEON.

Comment: Mine is not old compared to the list. I have 270x which is 2 years old.

Comment: But yes U have kindoff Hybrid system now: The [Xeon E3-1220 v2] (http://ark.intel.com/products/66416/Intel-BD82C216-PCH) has an Intel HD4000 as iGPU - Then U need to consider to completely switch it off in the MoBo BIOS. Sometimes it's possible to use both - and that's what obviously now is set. Again than U need to reboot into Recovery-Mode. Remember to use in Kubuntu _Systemsettings_ -> _Additional Drivers_  Also enable in the Software-Sources _Restricted Drivers"_ If anything is not clear just ask.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31873/discussion-between-andrius-chamentauskas-and-ellisistfroh).

Comment: regret I dont chat -never ever- function enabled in browser --- You should be able to start system in rescue mode. Then to root-Terminal-> enter `sudo apt-get purge fglrx*` `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf` `sudo initramfs -a` Any errors please report -> reboot

Comment: There was an error while purging `fglrx` but it seems it was purged anyway. I'm not sure if it's relevant, but here's log: http://pastie.org/10570298 . Also `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` did not exist, there were some others named similarly though. `sudo initramfs -a` failed however as I don't seem to have `initramfs`. All that said I was able to boot into Kubuntu, but I'd still like to use `fglrx`.

Comment: -see message b4 asking 2 chat. -> _Systemsettings_ -> _Additional Drivers_ System should now **not recognize** iGPU since BIOS-settings were changed. [FGLRX + FGLRX-updates are the same] -> (http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=wily&searchon=names&keywords=FGLRX) P.S.: Log lookes o.k. to me.

Comment: I don't think it ever did recognize iGPU, here's a screenshot http://collabshot.com/show/UBzyky though just in case I'm missing something. And yes I have "restricted" enabled in software sources.

Comment: _/var/log/gpu-manager-log_ revealed before and the Intel site says so too for this CPU. Fine so all the fixes from Alberto seem to work - you are now on Radeon the OSS-Driver. I'll be with until this is solved. Select FGLRX >>> | With 16.04 I would give Radeon a good chance beeing better than FGRLX ;-)

Comment: Still can't boot after selecting fglrx and then rebooting. Stuck on kubuntu logo boot screen. http://pastie.org/10570395 gpu-manager.log in case it helps.

Comment: Just remove temporarily _quiet splash_ from boot-parameter. or press cursor key up to see the boot-process were it gets stuck (before the login gets offered, right?) . I assume all updates are present?

Comment: All updates are installed. If I remove "quiet splash" I jsut get black screen. Clicking up arrow does nothing. Yes stuck before login screen just after grub screen.

Comment: Do U have disc-encryption activated?

Comment: No I don't have it

Comment: What i really don't understand the packages still seem to hang in the proposed pocket: The version in Question as install candidate should be -> 2:15.201-0ubuntu2~15.10.2 And if you compare this the results on top we are handling with too low a number.  Also see last comment in bug-report "verification needed"

Comment: So U have the choice: purge the fglrx as with the commands above in recovery-mode _again_. U are familiar wt this now! (big exuses I didn't discover this earlier, but u not either)  Enable proposed via GUI (won't ask U to use Nano as terminal-editor on commandline - if U are not trained wt this) enable the proposed-sources (u are tester than) use the GUI _"restricted drivers"_  reboot . **Disable sources   "proposed"**  **_  O R _** wait a few days until other testers have confirmed it works (whilst u have Radeon in use)

Comment: I'm familiar with command line, just not with linux structure in general. I'm willing to try out proposed packages, if there's better way to do this through command line I don't mind doing it that way

Comment: sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

just add the line _deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-proposed universe main multiverse restricted_  remove it lateron otherwise when u ever have to activate via GUI it might appear doubled and it throws an error. - last line of the file has to be empty. If the main-server doesn't work for u,   insert the one u prefer.

Comment: Καλό!, Andrius! U see error-analysis is sometimes lenghty and my attitude to it is to be rather patient&sometimes overcareful - when I would give someone commands that could brake the machine I would blame it. Take the line of the sources list- check if "proposed" is diabled. (The prefered method is to install only selected packages once testers are needed). Some tiny security updates are waiting. As an outcome of all this it would be nice if U could register @Launchpad & confirm it works 4U on yr hardware, after 1 or 2 days testing. In the end it looks so easy :-)