# Radeon HD 7730M driver fro Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, fglrx, amd-graphics

Currently my laptop is only using the onboard Intel graphics and not the Radeon HD 7730M card. I have a clean installation of Ubuntu 16.04 on the laptop and I have not made any changes to the graphical settings.

I tried to solve this problem by installing the ATI drivers for the card, but the .deb package I downloaded from their official site only supports Ubuntu 14.04. Next I tried installing the drivers as shown in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu), but I got errors stating that the packages can not be located. A few google searches later I found [this link.](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04)

If I understand the article in the link correct, there is no ATI drivers available for Xenial yet?

Any help on how I can solve this would be great.

Comment: Sorry, there will never be drivers for this chip again, AMD dropped support for many of there chips on Linux http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04

Comment: So the only way I can make use of this card is if I downgrade to 14.04?

Comment: Well, you can just use the drivers that come with 16.04, they will work but 3D acceleration is bad. If you want to play games or anything, yes downgrade. 14.04 is still supported until 2019, so a downgrade is not such a bad thing.

Comment: I'll give that a try, thank you for your help!